# Fill arrow SVG icon using percentage value from specific point

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this svg icon that I want to fill with color according to the percentage value, it's a chart, so it should start from the top left and fill all the way to the right following the line..

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLqpw.png)

```js
function setProgress(amt)
{
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amt);
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amt);
}


setProgress(0.60);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 254.25 233.26">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="progress" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0">
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="#bb8e89"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="#f4b6b0"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="Capa_2" data-name="Capa 2">
<g id="Capa_1-2" data-name="Capa 1">
<path class="cls-1" fill="url(#progress)" d="M254.25,17.72,235.32,0,216.38,17.72H227V92.93c0,66.6-25.41,124.48-104.17,124.48S18.63,159.53,18.63,92.93V52.35H0V92.14c0,76.11,32.18,141.12,122.79,141.12,89.77,0,122-65,122-141.12V17.72Z"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? As the progress value changes the fill changes so what do you want here?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change from the top point filling the whole frame, it makes it horizontal

Comment: You want x1="0" and y2="1" then (or maybe y1="1" depending on how you want it to fill).

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are after.

Exaneta is correct when he shows to use path `stroke` and not `fill`

With `stroke` you can use `stroke-dashArray="[percentage] 100"`

Only tricky part then is your *arrow-head*, to position it dynamically you need `animateMotion`

Using a native JSWC JavaScript Web Component because this is what they are meant to do

Making it reactive with *observed* attribute `percentage`

```html
<svg-percentage percentage="10"></svg-percentage>
<svg-percentage percentage="42"></svg-percentage>
<svg-percentage percentage="77"></svg-percentage>
```

creates:

[image]

Added an `onclick` for Stack Overflow Snippet demo only

```js
customElements.define("svg-percentage", class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["percentage"];
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attributeChangedCallback();
    this.onclick = () => this.setAttribute("percentage", ~~(Math.random()*100));
  }
  attributeChangedCallback() {
    let p = ~~(this.getAttribute("percentage") || 42);
    let d = "m10 52 0 40c0 181 230 181 225 0l0-92";
    let id = "p" + Math.random() * 1e18; // create a unique id
    this.innerHTML = `
<svg viewBox="-10 -25 260 280" stroke-width="15">
   <path id="${id}" d="${d}" fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"/>
   <path d="${d}" fill="none" stroke="lightgreen" 
         pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="${p} 100"/>
   <path d="m0 -15 30 15-30 15z" fill="green">         
     <animateMotion dur="0.001s" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" 
                    keyPoints="0;${p/100}" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
        <mpath href="#${id}"/>
      </animateMotion>
    </path>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" font-size="3em" text-anchor="middle">${p}%</text>
</svg>`;
  }
})
```

```html
<style>
  svg { max-height: 170px }
</style>

<svg-percentage percentage="10"></svg-percentage>
<svg-percentage percentage="42"></svg-percentage>
<svg-percentage percentage="77"></svg-percentage>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to draw a path that is following your shape. Mine is not perfect but still works.

```css
svg{width:90vh; border:solid;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 254.25 233.26">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="progress" x1="-1" >
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="#bb8e89"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="#f4b6b0"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="Capa_2" data-name="Capa 2">
<g id="Capa_1-2" data-name="Capa 1">

<path fill="url(#progress)" class="cls-1" d="M254.25,17.72 L235.32,0,216.38,17.72H227V92.93c0,66.6-25.41,124.48-104.17,124.48S18.63,159.53,18.63,92.93V52.35H0V92.14c0,76.11,32.18,141.12,122.79,141.12,89.77,0,122-65,122-141.12V17.72Z"/>

  <path stroke="black"  fill="none" id="pth" d="M10,52L10,92.14C10,273 240,273 235.32,92.14L235.32,0" />
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Next you set the width of the stroke to something big like 40 and you make the stroke="url(#progress)"

```css
svg{border:solid; width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 254.25 233.26">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="progress" x1="-1" >
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="#bb8e89"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="#f4b6b0"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="Capa_2" data-name="Capa 2">
<g id="Capa_1-2" data-name="Capa 1">

<path class="cls-1" d="M254.25,17.72 L235.32,0,216.38,17.72H227V92.93c0,66.6-25.41,124.48-104.17,124.48S18.63,159.53,18.63,92.93V52.35H0V92.14c0,76.11,32.18,141.12,122.79,141.12,89.77,0,122-65,122-141.12V17.72Z"/>

  <path stroke="url(#progress)"  fill="none" stroke-width="40" clip-path="url(#cp)" id="pth" d="M10,52L10,92.14C10,273 240,273 235.32,92.14L235.32,0"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Now you can use clipPath to clip the wide stroke with your shape:

```css
svg{border:solid; width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 254.25 233.26">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="progress" x1="-1" >
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="#bb8e89"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="#f4b6b0"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="Capa_2" data-name="Capa 2">
<g id="Capa_1-2" data-name="Capa 1">
  <clipPath id="cp">
<path class="cls-1" d="M254.25,17.72 L235.32,0,216.38,17.72H227V92.93c0,66.6-25.41,124.48-104.17,124.48S18.63,159.53,18.63,92.93V52.35H0V92.14c0,76.11,32.18,141.12,122.79,141.12,89.77,0,122-65,122-141.12V17.72Z"/>
  </clipPath> 
  <path stroke="url(#progress)"  fill="none" stroke-width="40" clip-path="url(#cp)" id="pth" d="M10,52L10,92.14C10,273 240,273 235.32,92.14L235.32,0" />
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Finaly you can set the stroke-dasharray of the path to whatever you need. Please observe that `pathLength="100"`

```js
function setProgress(amt)
{
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
 let s= 100*amt;
  document.getElementById("pth").setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${s},${100 - s}`);
}


setProgress(0.60);
```

```css
svg{width:90vh;border:solid}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 254.25 233.26">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="progress" x1="-1" >
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="#bb8e89"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="#f4b6b0"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="Capa_2" data-name="Capa 2">
<g id="Capa_1-2" data-name="Capa 1">
  <clipPath id="cp">
<path class="cls-1" d="M254.25,17.72 L235.32,0,216.38,17.72H227V92.93c0,66.6-25.41,124.48-104.17,124.48S18.63,159.53,18.63,92.93V52.35H0V92.14c0,76.11,32.18,141.12,122.79,141.12,89.77,0,122-65,122-141.12V17.72Z"/>
  </clipPath> 
  <path stroke="url(#progress)"  fill="none" stroke-width="40" clip-path="url(#cp)" id="pth" d="M10,52L10,92.14C10,273 240,273 235.32,92.14L235.32,0" pathLength="100" />
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank You !!! I tried to add the second background so that you can see the arrow that is filling up but without success, what should I do?

Comment: Update your question with all the issues

Comment: I am looking for the arrow to be complete, but to change color according to the %, up to X% a color, then the background color of the arrow, as in this example https://jsfiddle.net/seofoss/hvta583e/7/

Comment: In this case take a look at this demo https://codepen.io/giaco/pen/yGYmOQ

Comment: Thanks for your time, I managed to do it, but I don't think it's the right solution, I just added another svg below and put them together with CSS https://jsfiddle.net/byxr54na/1/